# How to add multiple PeekImage in tile?

Tags: uwp

I'm using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` class library.

I want to add **multiple** `PeekImage`, just like the **Microsoft Store**

```
var tileContent = new TileContent
{
    Visual = new TileVisual
    {
        TileWide = new TileBinding()
        {
            Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
            {
                PeekImage = new TilePeekImage
                {
                    Source = "Assets/512x512bb.jpg"
                },
                Children =
                {
                    new AdaptiveText
                    {
                        Text = "Jennifer Parker",
                        HintWrap = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var tileNotif = new TileNotification(tileContent.GetXml());
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotif);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Store tile uses the notification queue to achieve multiple tile notifications with peek images. See this article to [learn how to use the notification queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/01/05/quickstart-how-to-use-the-tile-notification-queue-with-local-notifications/).

Simply use a different peek image on each notification you send.